# I'm Methodist..I don't understand sanctification

Tags: methodist

Im Methodist..my mom is sanctified..I don't understand the Holy Spirit..it scares me..she preaches over me and prays over me like I'm here guinea pig, instead of getting behind the pulpit..I can't live my life comfortably because every move I make she says I'm going to hell or being disobedient and I'm 42 years old. When she prays it feels like someone is putting voodoo on me..it's very uncomfortable. I feel like she's harassing me..how can I make her stop throwing her religion on me without my permission

Comment: _Like any library, Christianity Stack Exchange offers great information, but does not offer personalized advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your pastor, priest, or other trustworthy counselor._

Comment: You might be able to rephrase this question in a way that just asks the question.  It may be that she's misinterpreting something her religion says (or not employing the requisite  amount of tact) so it would be good to get the facts.  Or it could be that she's doing her duty (I don't know a ton about Methodism so I can't comment) - but the last part of the question "how can I make her stop" is not a question we can answer objectively for you here.

Comment: I don't want to put words into your mouth, but you could probably ask "why is she harasing me" instead of "how can I make her stop"

Comment: Go talk to  your church leader about this. Tell him/her what your mother is doing. It's really not about the nature of sanctification.

Comment: An acceptable question might ask what do Methodists believe about sanctification and the Holy Spirit.  It would also be helpful if any question you ask does not get personal but focuses on what the Bible says about such things.

Comment: Confront and resist her and be strong, or start living separately.

Answer (score 1):

The subject of sanctification is deep, requiring a long, careful study of what the Bible says about it, and what God's view of being sanctified means - to him. Further, having a deep head-knowledge of sanctification as a subject will do nobody any good as to being sanctified by God because sanctification is based on his calling, and his enabling. Conversely, many unlearned, even illiterate people, have come to discover what sanctification means to them by God sanctifying them.

To be sanctified by God is to be called by him to a cleansed, saved state so that he can use you in holy, sanctified service that will bring honour to his holy name.
Here is a quote from a theology book about what the word means:

> "Sanctification - The same act of faith that receives Christ for
> justification receives Christ for renewal of the inner self, and one
> day the outer self (glorification).
>
> While justification is a legal development made once and for all,
> sanctification is a gradual process by which the Spirit conforms us to
> the image of Christ through the gospel.
>
> While sanctification is God's gracious work... we are exhorted to put
> to death the deeds of the flesh and to bear the fruit of the Spirit."
> *Pilgrim Theology*, Michael Horton, p.477, Zondervan 2011

Really, that is the only part of your question that can be answered on this site - saying something about the theology of the matter of God sanctifying an individual. But anyone talking about it without actually being sanctified, will never understand what it means.